# Get Site Template ECMAScript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

I have an ECMA script that I'm using to build a site directory (Thank you Bill Simser). I'm trying to add additional information such as the template the site is using, and not having much luck finding all of the properties I can utilize.

I'm attempting to add something like:

```
var template = item.get_template();
```

but this is not a valid property for ecmascript.

here is the script I'm using:

```
        while(items.moveNext())
    {
        try
        {
            var item = items.get_current();
            var itemUrl = item.get_serverRelativeUrl();
            var title = item.get_title();
            var template = item.get_template();
            var lastItemModified = getModifiedDateString(new Date(item.get_lastItemModifiedDate()));

            menuNavContent += '<li>';
            menuNavContent += '<a href="' + itemUrl + '">' + title + '</a>';
            menuNavContent += '</li>';

            contentNavContent += '<div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="';
            contentNavContent += "location.href='" + itemUrl + "';";
            contentNavContent += '">';
            contentNavContent += '<li class="theme_blue">';
            contentNavContent += '<div>';

            contentNavContent += '<div class="tileTitle">' + title + '</div>';
            contentNavContent += '<div class="tileSubtitle">' + lastItemModified + '</div>';

            contentNavContent += '</div>';
            contentNavContent += '</li>';
            contentNavContent += '</div>';
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            menuNavContent = err.name;
            contentNavContent = err.message;
        }
    }

    menuNavContent += '</ul>';
    menuNavContent += '</div>';
    $('#menuNav').html(menuNavContent);

    contentNavContent += '</ul>';
    contentNavContent += '</div>';
    $('#contentNav').html(contentNavContent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webTemplate property is not exposed by the SP.js in 2010. (It is however in 2013: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj838541.aspx).  However, there is a JS variable written to the page with the web template name: g_wsaSiteTemplateId.  Without any server-side code, etc., that would be the only identifying mark of the template.

Comment: nice 1, I read about it somewhere but wasn't coming into my mind :) !